# How to exit from a Python program using MacFSEvents using Ctrl-C

Tags: python, macos

I'm using MacFSEvents, a Python library that monitors a directory for changes on Mac OS X, like so:

```
# from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MacFSEvents/
from fsevents import Observer
from fsevents import Stream
observer = Observer()

def callback(event):
    print event.name

stream = Stream(callback, '.', file_events=True)
observer.schedule(stream)
observer.start()
```

When I run this script in the Terminal, hitting Ctrl-C doesn't exit the program -- the only way I can find to kill it is with 'kill' in a separate window, or with Activity Monitor, etc.

Any ideas on how to make such a program killable by Ctrl-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to look for `KeyboardInterrupt` and stop the observer manually (as an alternative to `observer.run()`):

```
def better_run(observer):
   try:
      observer.start()
      while True:      # instead of this infinite loop, you can do
         pass          # whatever processing you wanted
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      observer.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer, by the way, is the little known Ctrl-\, which sends SIGQUIT to the process, and will quit it no matter how hung.

Comment: Actually, doesn't work for this particular issue for some reason, even when you're capturing events using `signal`: `(python)10:23:52 (~/src/work/broadcastr/scripts/python)
todd@megabarley> python filewatcher.py /tmp/test1 /tmp/test2
^\^\`

Comment: It actually does work for me, sort of. Rather than quitting cleanly, though, it crashes, causing OSX to pop up a "Python quit unexpectedly" dialog. This is still slightly more convenient than using `kill`, though.